# why does this Sqoop command to list tables in an Oracle database not work?

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I tried to list out the tables in a Oracle Database by using following Sqoop command:

```
sqoop list-tables --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//10.13.25.118:1521/udc.ds.dtvops.net --username xxxx --password xxxx
```

But I get this error:

```
13/11/12 16:34:58 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
13/11/12 16:34:58 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
13/11/12 16:34:59 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to GMT`
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

Sqoop is a tool of tools and list-tables is one of them.

Syntax to use list-tables:

```
sqoop list-tables --connect <> --username <> --password <>
```

In your case, just try

```
sqoop list-tables --connect jdbc:oracle:thin@10.13.25.118:1521/db_name --username xxxx --password xxxx
```

Write your database name in place of `db_name`.

Answer (score 0):

The list-tables tool in Oracle build-in connector is limited to tables that are owned by the user who is used for the connection itself. Check out the [query](https://github.com/apache/sqoop/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/sqoop/manager/OracleManager.java#L88) that Sqoop will execute.

The list-tables tool is more an exploring option than a tool for production use, so I would recommend to simply import the tables you need. Considering that you are using different username for logging into Oracle then the owner of the table, you will need to specify the owner on the command line in the --table parameter:

sqoop import ... --table OWNER.TABLE

Answer (score 0):

You may have to start the oracle and http service first if they are not running.

start service for Apache http and oracle (Example: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition)

```
sudo service httpd start
sudo service oracle-xe start
```

Then, you may run the sqoop command

```
sqoop list-tables --connect jdbc:oracle:thin@10.13.25.118:1521/db_name --username xxxx --password xxx
```